# I'm using prerender-spa-plugin and it works, but Google doesn't see the prerendered pages

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, prerender

I have a Vue.js application and I want to use prerendering for SEO purposes.

I followed the [github](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin), [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-prerender-prerenderer/), [this one](https://symmetrycode.com/better-vue-seo-with-prerender-spa-plugin-and-vue-cli/), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWDcSRHBC9M) to understand everything and I ended up with this implementation in my app:

in `webpack.prod.conf.js`:

```
...
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
...
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')
const PuppeteerRenderer = PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer
...
plugins: [

 new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
  staticDir: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'), 
  routes: ['/', '/about-gy', '/gy-quest'], 
  headless: false,
  renderer: new PuppeteerRenderer()
 })

]
```

in `main.js` (if it matters somehow):

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store: store,
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

The results I get are as expected I think; in the `dist` folder it looks like this:

```
dist
--about-gy
  +--index.html
--gy-quest
  +--index.html
--static
--index.html
```

Where the html files have the CSS and HTML rendered.

**The problem is** that when I test the same way the guy in the video tests (with view page source on the rendered pages) I get only the "app" div inside and not the already rendered one. 
I thought maybe it's because it's on a local server or something, tried to Fetch as Google on the Search Console tool they offer, and still, they fetch the not-rendered version of the pages.

I'm stuck because it's not an issue I can write on the github of the plugin because the plugin does its job, but I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `webpack.prod.conf.js` add an option to `renderer: new PuppeteerRenderer()` that tells it to run once the app has been mounted:

```
renderer: new PuppeteerRenderer({
  renderAfterElementExists: "#app"
})
```